# Adding a height property to binary search tree

Tags: binary-search-tree

I have been given a Binary Search Tree class which is used to implement a Set. It has all the basic functionality, insert, remove and checking whether a particular value exists or not. The Node class used for the tree has also been provided. The node has an unused class variable `height`.

```
class TreeNode{
    .......
    public int height;
    .......
}
```

That is an oversimplified version of the node class. Now I am supposed to write a new class that extends the functionality of this class by using this `height` in order track the height of each node, where the height is:

- 0, if node has no subtrees,
- -1 for empty
- 1+ height of largest subtree.

The catch here is that I cannot modify the code given to me, neither can I simply copy a large part of existing code and modify it to suit my needs, ie, I have to call the super class function `add()` and then add some code to update height, and this code should add only a constant to the runtime of the entire function. I have come up with a solution where I call `super.add()` and then I go along the search path for the newly added element in order to update the heights. Although this works, it is a very messy solution.

My current solution works as follows:

- Call `super.add()`, which itself is a recursive function(the standard add function for BST)
- Now that the element is added, call a private helper function which takes the value that has been added, searches for it recursively, and then updates the height information along that search path.

I just want a hint here, since I feel like there is something that I'm missing and I feel like I'm at a mental roadblock. Refrain from posting source code. Answers which are actually counter questions that force me to think are also appreciated.

Comment: Adding this little code is not enough in my opinion :) Make sure you post your solution so people can help with it and not try to guess what you already did and why it is messy.

Comment: Thanks! I have already added the algorithm for my code. I did not post the actual code since this is an algorithm level problem rather than language specific issue.

Comment: What other variables does the node class have?

I am assuming the height is -1 if some variable say value = null. and 0 if value != null but either one or both of leftChild and rightChild exist.

Comment: The node class has a left and the right. The data is a string field, not generic. And your assumption for height is correct